# Google address autocomplete for multiple input in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-maps-api-2

I am struggling with implementing google address autocomplete inside an `ng-repeat` in angularJS.

I have an `ng-repeat` loop to print some HTML.

```
<table>           
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Street</th>
            <th>City</th>
            <th>State</th>
            <th>Zip</th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="location in assetLocations track by $index">          
            <td>
                <input type="text" class="street_edit_group form-control" ng-model="location.Street__c" id="{{$index}}">    
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="location.City__c">    
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="location.State__c">
            <td>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="location.Zip__c">    
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I want to implement google address autocomplete in `street_edit_group` class for each input.

```
<input type="text" class="street_edit_group form-control" ng-model="location.Street__c" id="{{$index}}">
```

for this, what I have done in Controller is,

```
$scope.autocompleteAssetLocationEdit = null;

 $scope.initialize = function() {
            var clsname = document.getElementsByClassName('street_edit_group');

            for (var i = 0; i < clsname.length; i++) {
                var id = clsname[i].id;
                $scope.autocompleteAssetLocationEdit = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(

                (document.getElementById(id)), {
                    types: ['geocode']
                });

                $scope.autocompleteAssetLocationEdit.addListener('place_changed', function () { $scope.fillInEditAddress() });
            }
  };
```

And, in `$scope.fillInEditAddress()`, I have

```
    $scope.fillInEditAddress = function(){
                    var streetNumber = '';
                    var street = '';
                    var city = '';
                    var stateCode = '';
                    var zipCode = '';

                    var place = $scope.autocompleteAssetLocationEdit.getPlace();
                    console.log(place);
};
```

But, `$scope.autocompleteAssetLocationEdit.getPlace();` is not fetching any place there.

What is wrong with my code?

Comment: try console.log($scope.autocompleteAssetLocationEdit) to see if there's getPlace() function in the object

Comment: As per my point of view, You should create one directive for load goolge autocomplete address.

Comment: @holydragon: getPlace() is there with no data :(